# Powershell remote vistor a share disk by pssession faild on windows server 2016

Tags: powershell

The system version is **`WINDOWS SERVER 2016`**, I use PowerShell to remote the computer then vistor a Shared disk, but it replay to me "The specified server cannot perform the requested operation".  It is work on **`WINDOWS SERVER 2012`**, is this a problem about remote account right or else?

The Script is like this:

```
$Password = "xxxxxxxxx"
$UserName= "Jenkinsadmin"

$DestWebServer = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
$CompanyCode = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
function CreateNasDir($CompanyCode,$NasDir)
{
    Write-Host "TT"
    if(!(test-path ${NasDir}${CompanyCode}))
    {
        Write-Host "fff"
        new-item -itemtype "directory" -path "${NasDir}${CompanyCode}"
        Write-host "HEHE"
        Write-Host "DD"
    }
    Write-Host "YY"
}

$PasswordSecure = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($UserName,$PasswordSecure)

$WebSession = New-PSSession -computername $DestWebServer -credential $Cred

Invoke-Command -Session $WebSession -ScriptBlock ${function:CreateNasDir} -ArgumentList $CompanyCode,"\\xxxxxxxxx\myshare\"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if SMB 1.0 has been configured on the scratched 10.

1. Run PowerShell as Administrator
2. Set-SmbClientConfiguration -RequireSecuritySignature 1

Answer Y when prompted to confirm the modification.

3. Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters" RequireSecureNegotiate -Value 0 -Force

Then open turn Features on and off to check the SMB 1.0:

Control Panel / Programs and Features / Turn Windows Features On or Off and make sure SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support is ticked

Check in your windows server 2012r2 whether the SMB checked or not.